# Add overlay to an image

Tags: css

I wanted to add an overlay to an image if they hovered over the image.

I have tried plenty of ways but the image just seems to disappear or stay the same.

This is what it will be like

```
<a id="icon"
  style="background: url(/images/layout/top/icon.gif); height:23px; width:23px; float:left; margin-right:3px;"
  href="page.php?pageid=123" title="Icon">
</a>
```

Really and truly, what I am after is a quick way to have the image change without having to make more images.

So when not hovering over the image - Original image
When hovering over the image - 40% color overlay?

Thanks in advanced.

**What I tried:**

```
a.thumbnail {
background-color:orange;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=40, Style=0); 
-moz-opacity: 40%; 
opacity: 0.4; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a little fiddle that has this doesn't overlay, but gives the same effect using just CSS. Plus, I threw in some CSS transitions for fun. Basically creating a div behind the image that is revealed via pseudo element hover. This way you can drop in your  tags still without needing to create CSS background images like crazy. Just swap out the alpha stuff to make the overlay work the other way.

http://jsfiddle.net/wesleyterry/jwXvA/#base

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Wrong way round, but its what I'm after! How is it fading?

Comment: I used CSS transitions to fade it. If their browsers don't support those yet, it will gracefully degrade to just swapping out the alpha on the image. I've updated the fiddle so it works the other way now. http://jsfiddle.net/wesleyterry/jwXvA/

Comment: So, all that `-moz-transition:` stuff creates the nice fade effect too.

Comment: -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";

That fixed it :)

Comment: But any reason as to why its fading to black when its set to white? LOL. It works fine on the test, copy and pasted over and it does it in black...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if it's an overlay you can assume the height and width is probably going to be the same.

in this demo i accidentally used images sized 25. change to 23

http://jsfiddle.net/raU2J/7/

```
<div class="overlay_wrapper">
   <a href="#"></a>
   <div class="overlay"></div>
   <img src="cake.jpg" />
</div>​


.overlay,
.overlay_wrapper a,
.overlay_wrapper {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay_wrapper a {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=40, Style=0); 
  -moz-opacity: 40%; 
  opacity: 0.4; 
  z-index: 9;
}​
```

jquery:

```
$(".overlay_wrapper").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with just the single `<a>`, but you can put the `<a>` in a container (a span or a div). Give the container the desired background, and give `a:hover` a background color like `rgba(255, 255, 255,.4)`.

If that doesn't work like you want, explain more about your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The sample demo:

`html`

```
<div class="img"><div class="overlap"></div></div>
```

`css`

```
.img {width:100px;height:100px;background:red;position:relative;}
.overlap { visibility:hidden;}
.hover .overlap {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;height:100px;background:#333;filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* for IE */  -moz-opacity:0.4; opacity: 0.4;-khtml-opacity: 0.4; visibility:visible;}
```